# Identity SignInManager PasswordSignInAsync success but it doesnt redirect to anywhere stuck in loading

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

Hi i use identity on my project. When customer logins it is success but on 1st try its stuck in loading if i redirect manually from url it goes on page normally but on its own its just stuck. If i will sign out after and sign in again it works perfectly. it happens only on 1st time of loading project. my codei s

```
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
            // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Username, model.Password, true, lockoutOnFailure: false);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Product");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("Login", "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
            }
        }
```

and in start up code is like

```
/services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        //{
        //    options.ConsentCookie.IsEssential = true;//<--NOTE THIS
        //    options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false;
        //    options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        //});
        //services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
        //    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

        services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie(options =>
{
    //options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;//<--NOTE THIS
    //options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    //options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
    //options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
    options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
    options.LogoutPath = "/Account/Logout";
    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/AccessDenied"; // If the AccessDeniedPath is not set here, ASP.NET Core will default to /Account/AccessDenied  
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(720);
    //options.SlidingExpiration = true;
});
```

i have tried many other options and things but none worked
this are options i tried.

```
  services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.ConsentCookie.IsEssential = true;//<--NOTE THIS
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie(options =>
{
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;//<--NOTE THIS
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
    options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
    options.LogoutPath = "/Account/Logout";
    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/AccessDenied"; // If the AccessDeniedPath is not set here, ASP.NET Core will default to /Account/AccessDenied  
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(720);
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
});

        //services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        //{
        //    // Cookie settings  
        //    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        //    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(720);
        //    options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login"; // If the LoginPath is not set here, ASP.NET Core will default to /Account/Login  
        //    options.LogoutPath = "/Account/Logout"; // If the LogoutPath is not set here, ASP.NET Core will default to /Account/Logout  
        //    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/AccessDenied"; // If the AccessDeniedPath is not set here, ASP.NET Core will default to /Account/AccessDenied  
        //    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
        //});
```

Comment: have you debugged your code,and is `result.Succeeded` true?

Comment: yes its true all time but on 1st true it just dont redirects. if i will give it url with hand it goes in authorized controllers without problem.